# Prove $S/\operatorname{Ker}(\alpha) \cong (\operatorname{Im}\alpha)$ where $\alpha: S \rightarrow T$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Prove $S/\operatorname{Ker}(\alpha) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha: S \rightarrow T$ is a ring homomorphism.

Proof: Let $A = S/\operatorname{Ker}(\alpha)$, $B = \operatorname{Im}(\alpha)$

Then $\alpha$ induces a map $\tilde{\alpha}: S/\operatorname{Ker}(\alpha) \rightarrow \operatorname{Im}(\alpha)$. This map is given by: $\tilde{\alpha}(\tilde{x})=\alpha(x)$.

To show that this map is well defined, suppose $\tilde{y} \in \operatorname{Ker}(\alpha)$, then we have:

$\tilde{\alpha}(\tilde{x}+\tilde{y})=\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)=\alpha(x)+0=\alpha(x)$

Let $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y} \in S/\operatorname{Ker}(\alpha)$ and suppose $\tilde{\alpha}(\tilde{x})=\tilde{\alpha}(\tilde{y})$. This implies that $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$, and thus $\alpha(x-y)=\alpha(x)-\alpha(y)=0$.

Thus $x-y \in \operatorname{Ker}(\alpha)$ and so $\tilde{x}=\tilde{y}$. Thus $\tilde{\alpha}$ is one-to-one.

Now let $z \in \operatorname{Im}(\alpha)$, then $\exists s \in S$ such that $\alpha(s)=z$. This implies that $s \neq 0$ and so $\tilde{\alpha}(\tilde{s})=z$.

Thus $\tilde{\alpha}$ is bijective, and it is also a ring homomorphism as it was induced by a ring homomorphism. Therefore $\tilde{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism.

Q.E.D.

How does this look? I feel like there is a lot I could make more explicit / sharpen up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot comment yet, I'll give you my thoughts here:

One thing you did not mention is the definition of the induced morphism $\bar{\alpha}$. Then you would also need to check, that this definition, which depends on choosing a representative, is well defined.

In your proof of surjectivity, you don't get that $s\neq 0$. But this is not needed anyway.

Apart from that your proof is complete and correct.

Comment: I edited my answer to show well defined. Does this look correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof of well defined is correct, but there is a typo in the definition of $\bar{\alpha}$.